# Redirect anonymous user to login page

Tags: 7, redirection

I need to redirect an anonymous user when they hit the url 'node/add/project' to 'user/login' - otherwise, just leave them enter that url.

Not sure if I'm going about this the correct way (probably not as it doesn't appear to work!) - Can someone shed some light, or advice!

```
function local_menu() {
    $items['node/add/project'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'local_project_anonymous',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}

function local_project_anonymous(){
    global $user;
    if($user->uid == 0){
        drupal_goto('user/login');
    }   
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Why don't you create a permission, and use it for the menu callback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function MODULE_init(){
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid == 0  && $_GET['q'] == 'node/add/project' ) {
    drupal_goto('user/login');
  }
}
```

Comment: This causes problems with drush. To prevent that you can use if (!function_exists('drush_main')) { ... } to check if you're in drush environment . See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825256/drush-status-unrecoverable-error-caused-by-drupal-goto-in-hook-init

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module.

> The LoginToboggan module offers several modifications of the Drupal login system in an external module by offering the following features and usability improvements:
>
> - Allow users to login using either their username OR their e-mail address.
> - **Allow users to login immediately.**
> - **Provide a login form on Access Denied pages for non-logged-in (anonymous) users.**
> - The module provides two login block options: One uses JavaScript to display the form within the block immediately upon clicking "log in". The other brings the user to a separate page, but returns the user to their original page upon login.
> - Customize the registration form with two e-mail fields to ensure accuracy.
> - Optionally redirect the user to a specific page when using the 'immediate login' feature.
> - Optionally redirect the user to a specific page upon validation of their e-mail address.
> - Optionally display a user message indicating a successful login.
> - Optionally combine both the login and registration form on one page.
> - Optionally have unvalidated users purged from the system at a pre-defined interval.
> - Integrates with the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module to do various tasks when a user validates via email validation process (see http://drupal.org/node/880904 for an example).

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan is made for this!