# How to redirect a to a differnet url?

Tags: 7

When the user makes a request to www.mysite.com/user he should be redirected to www.mysite.com/user/login. Is there any way by which i can do this. THought of using hook_boot and drupal_goto or headers. But not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? if the user is already logged in, /user displays the account profile. If not, it presents the login form just as if you had browsed to /user/login .

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/32805/1504

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a permanent redirect like that, I'd set up a [301 Redirect](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php) in the .htaccess file.

```
  RewriteRule ^old_file_name http://www.example.com/new-file-name [R=301,L]
```

If for some reason you aren't able to modify your .htaccess file, there's the [Global Redirect Module](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) (supported in D7 and D6) as well.

Comment: Is there a reason this was unaccepted? Is it not accurate?

Comment: Oh, that's ok. My dash just showed that it was accepted and then unaccepted again. Either way, thanks.