# Redirect Anonymous user to login page

Tags: 8, routes, redirection, event-subscribers

I want if user not logged in and visit any page of my website **except my REST VIEWS routers** I redirect him/her to  login page in drupal 8,  I found this solutions for drupal 7 but didn't find any solution for Drupal 8,

- [Redirect anonymous user to login page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32804/redirect-anonymous-user-to-login-page)
- [How to redirect anonymous users to login page using Rules module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50300/how-to-redirect-anonymous-users-to-login-page-using-rules-module)

Comment: In code you would write an event subscriber to act on `KernelEvents::REQUEST` event and then set the response to a RedirectResponse for the login page.

Comment: I thought of something else. You could set the 403 page to `/user` and then if they're anonymous, it would take them to `/user/login`, but with the side effect of taking authenticated users to their user profile without telling them they've been denied access to the page they were looking for.

Comment: Use the following module to add a login redirect for anonymous users, it has a setting to exclude paths so I think you can add your rest paths in that. https://www.drupal.org/project/anonymous_redirect

Comment: This module also does the job: https://www.drupal.org/project/anonymous_login

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can test a user's status very early with event subscriber in a custom module that subscribes to KernelEvents::REQUEST.

First, you register the event subscriber in `mymodule.services.yml` in your module folder:

```
services:
  mymodule.event_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\RedirectAnonymousSubscriber
    arguments: []
    tags:
      - {name: event_subscriber}
```

Then add `RedirectAnonymousSubscriber.php`  for your custom event subscriber in your module in the `/src/EventSubscriber/` folder.

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

/**
 * Event subscriber subscribing to KernelEvents::REQUEST.
 */
class RedirectAnonymousSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  public function __construct() {
    $this->account = \Drupal::currentUser();
  }

  public function checkAuthStatus(GetResponseEvent $event) {

    if ($this->account->isAnonymous() && \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() != 'user.login') {

      // add logic to check other routes you want available to anonymous users,
      // otherwise, redirect to login page.
      $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
      if (strpos($route_name, 'view') === 0 && strpos($route_name, 'rest_') !== FALSE) {
        return;
      }

      $response = new RedirectResponse('/user/login', 301);
      $event->setResponse($response);
      $event->stopPropagation();
    }
  }

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = array('checkAuthStatus');
    return $events;
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks to @mradcliffe for the idea for the event subscriber

Comment: he should create `RedirectAnonymousSubscriber.php` ,I update your answer.

Comment: @oknate what if user is on /registration or /forget-password or /logout route ? Shouldn't it check for those routes as well in the if condition ? As as per this, the user might be redirect while registering or request for the new password.

Comment: Another important detail here is "priority" of the subscriber. I found some routes will resolve before the redirect above kicks in. But setting the priority (a higher number fires first) helps to resolve that. In the example above, use array('checkAuthStatus', 100). Docs on subscriber and priority: https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html

Comment: The redirect shouldn't have a 301 status, since the redirect shouldn't be cached by the browser. I think it should be 302 instead.

Comment: Thanks oknate for this snippet. I've had to tweak it a bit to also allow other user paths like password reset etc. https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/redirect-anonymous-users-login-form-drupal-8-9

Comment: It seems this doesn't work in newer versions of Drupal

Answer (score 9):

First, create a service for your event subscriber in `module-name.services.yml`

**Code** -

```
services:
    [MODULE-NAME]_event_subscriber:
        class: Drupal\MODULE-NAME\EventSubscriber\[Event-Subscriber-class]
        tags:
        - {name: event_subscriber}
```

Create your own eventsubscriber class inside `modules/module-name/src/EventSubscriber` directory:

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class Event-Subscriber-class implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  private $redirectCode = 301;

  public function checkForRedirection2(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $account = \Drupal::currentUser(); 
    if (empty($account->id()) {
      $response = new RedirectResponse('/', $this->redirectCode);
      $response->send();
      exit(0);
    }
  }

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = array('checkForRedirection2');
    return $events;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

On Drupal 8.3.3, this code causes an endless redirection. I've fixed that by adding that instead.

```
..
$response = new RedirectResponse('/user/login', 301);
$response->send();
..
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is compatible for Drupal 8, and 9.

First, you register the event subscriber in `redirect_anonymous_users.services.yml` in your module folder (taken from [**@oknate**'s answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/223109/106056)):

```
services:
  redirect_anonymous_users.event_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\redirect_anonymous_users\EventSubscriber\RedirectAnonymousSubscriber
    arguments: []
    tags:
      - {name: event_subscriber}
```

Then add RedirectAnonymousSubscriber.php for your custom event subscriber in your module in the `/src/EventSubscriber/` folder.

```
namespace Drupal\redirect_anonymous_users\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

/**
 * Event subscriber subscribing to KernelEvents::REQUEST.
 */
class RedirectAnonymousSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  public function checkAuthStatus(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    if (
      \Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous() &&
      \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() != 'user.login'
    ) {
      $response = new RedirectResponse('/user/login', 302);
      $response->send();
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = array('checkAuthStatus');

    return $events;
  }

}
```

Comment: Nice example! But it wold be better if it used Dependency Injection instead of hard-wired calls to `\Drupal::currentUser()` and `\Drupal::routeMatch()`.