# If a user does not have a role, keep redirecting them to the same form until they complete it?

Tags: 8, redirection

I have a form/node that I want all users to complete after logging in for the first time.  When the user completes the form (saves the node), they are automatically awarded the `completed` role.

If a user does not have the `completed` role, I want to keep redirecting them to the form no matter what links they click.

In Drupal 7, I could do this with Rules (event: content is viewed, condition: user does not have role, action: redirect).  However, in Drupal 8, Rules is still in alpha and I can't get it to work without crashing my site.  So what hook should I use to do this programmatically? (what's the hook for "user views a node"?)

Comment: The hook you are looking for is an event subscriber, see for example https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223095/redirect-anonymous-user-to-login-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`hook_entity_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_view/8.2.x), this is called when a user views any entity type, also [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view/8.2.x) can be used if you want to redirect on specific entity type view like node.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do this.

1. Find all the blocks that print links (User account menu, Footer, Main navigation, etc.)
2. Configure the display settings for each block to "hide" the block on `/node/*/edit`.

By hiding all the links, the user will have to click "save" before being able to proceed to a different page.

However, this solution removes all the links from all node edit pages, which is a big tradeoff compared to what the question asks for (a way to redirect the user if they click a link-- this solution is just hiding all the links that can be clicked).