# Can't use exit(0), how else can I terminate a response?

Tags: 8

Here's my code(using Drupal 8):

```
public function checkForRedirection(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $is_authenticated = $this->currentUser->isAuthenticated();
    $route_name = $this->routeMatch->getRouteName();

    if (!$is_authenticated && $route_name !== "user.login") {
      header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
      header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", FALSE);
      header("Pragma: no-cache");
      define("SITE", "www.google.com");
      $response = new RedirectResponse(SITE, $this->redirectCode);
      $response->send();
      $exit(0);
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ["checkForRedirection", 30];
    return $events;
  }
```

So I'm redirecting an authenticated user away from my site. It works perfectly how I want it to, the only problem is PHP Mess Detector doesn't allow the exit(0) function, so wondering what are my alternatives to produce same functionality that exit(0) does here?

Comment: You need `$event->setResponse($response);`, see for example https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/223109/47547. This stops the propagation of the event and finishes the Drupal kernel, even without the need for `$event->stopPropagation();` which the code example is using.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to terminate using the kernel. You'll have to generate `$currentRequest` and `$response`, which may already be available depending on where your code lies. After you have them, you can terminate the request using:

```
\Drupal::service('kernel')->terminate($currentRequest, $response);
```

Comment: You can't terminate a symfony http kernel from the inside with this command. The terminate method of the kernel is called from the outside after the main run of the kernel has finished.